# How to use Python socket to build a websocket server that can receive and send image？

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

The example  looks like this
python server

```
import socket
import struct
import hashlib
import base64


def get_headers(data):
    headers = {}
    data = str(data, encoding="utf-8")

    header, body = data.split("\r\n\r\n", 1)

    header_list = header.split("\r\n")

    for i in header_list:
        i_list = i.split(":", 1)
        if len(i_list) >= 2:
            headers[i_list[0]] = "".join(i_list[1::]).strip()
        else:
            i_list = i.split(" ", 1)
            if i_list and len(i_list) == 2:
                headers["method"] = i_list[0]
                headers["protocol"] = i_list[1]
    return headers

def parse_payload(payload):
    payload_len = payload[1] & 127
    if payload_len == 126:
        extend_payload_len = payload[2:4]
        mask = payload[4:8]
        decoded = payload[8:]

    elif payload_len == 127:
        extend_payload_len = payload[2:10]
        mask = payload[10:14]
        decoded = payload[14:]
    else:
        extend_payload_len = None
        mask = payload[2:6]
        decoded = payload[6:]

    # 
    bytes_list = bytearray()

    for i in range(len(decoded)):
        # 
        chunk = decoded[i] ^ mask[i % 4]
        bytes_list.append(chunk)
    body = str(bytes_list, encoding='utf-8')
    return body


def send_msg(conn, msg_bytes):
    token = b"\x81"
    length = len(msg_bytes)
    if length < 126:
        token += struct.pack("B", length)
    elif length <= 0xFFFF:
        token += struct.pack("!BH", 126, length)
    else:
        token += struct.pack("!BQ", 127, length)

    msg = token + msg_bytes
    conn.sendall(msg)
    return True


def server_socket():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 10083))
    sock.listen(5)
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print(conn)
    data = conn.recv(8096)
    headers = get_headers(data)
    # 
    response_tpl = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" \
                   "Upgrade:websocket\r\n" \
                   "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" \
                   "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: %s\r\n" \
                   "WebSocket-Location: ws://%s\r\n\r\n"

    magic_string = '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11'

    if headers.get('Sec-WebSocket-Key'):
        value = headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'] + magic_string

    ac = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha1(value.encode('utf-8')).digest())
    response_str = response_tpl % (ac.decode('utf-8'), headers.get("Host"))
    conn.sendall(bytes(response_str, encoding="utf-8"))

    while True:
        data_1 = conn.recv(8096)
```

**The main thing is how to parse long data here**

```
        data_2 = parse_payload(data_1)

        print(data_2)
        send_msg(conn, data_2.encode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server_socket()
```

I use websocket  web client.When I send some short text is okay.sending long data like image base64 is wrong.
I can't understand this:

```
Frame format:

      0                   1                   2                   3
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
     +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+-------------------------------+
     |F|R|R|R| opcode|M| Payload len |    Extended payload length    |
     |I|S|S|S|  (4)  |A|     (7)     |             (16/64)           |
     |N|V|V|V|       |S|             |   (if payload len==126/127)   |
     | |1|2|3|       |K|             |                               |
     +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
     |     Extended payload length continued, if payload len == 127  |
     + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-------------------------------+
     |                               |Masking-key, if MASK set to 1  |
     +-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
     | Masking-key (continued)       |          Payload Data         |
     +-------------------------------- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
     :                     Payload Data continued ...                :
     + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
     |                     Payload Data continued ...                |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I try to send and receive image base64 data of an image, but Parse  data without success.
How to parse long  data?

Comment: I don't think you are fully implementing the websocket protocol. You need to use that protocol on both send and receive. Maybe find an existing Python websocket library.

Comment: FYI:  The websocket protocol: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#format